# TSQL Syntax to increment on group of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with syntax to increment a column based on grouping of 2 columns.

The following shows the desired output where I want to show an increment for each ID split by DateTime

[image]

I've tried the following without success

```
SELECT hl.ts_DateTime,  
       hl.Tagname as [ID],  
       hl.TagValue as [Value],
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY hl.Tagname, ts_datetime) AS RowFilter
FROM   Table1 hl 
ORDER  BY hl.Tagname,  hl.ts_DateTime


SELECT hl.ts_DateTime,  
       hl.Tagname as [ID],  
       hl.TagValue as [Value],
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ts_DateTime, Tagname  ORDER BY ts_DateTime ASC)  AS RowFilter
FROM   Table1 hl 
ORDER  BY hl.Tagname,  hl.ts_DateTime
```

Example sqlfiddle => http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/131c8/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT hl.ts_DateTime,  
       hl.Tagname as [ID],  
       hl.TagValue as [Value],
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY hl.Tagname ORDER BY hl.ts_DateTime) AS RowFilter
FROM   Table1 hl 
ORDER  BY hl.Tagname,  hl.ts_DateTime
```